# R bookdown gitbook - how to override table style

Tags: r, bookdown

I like the gitbook style in general, but some tables (particularly regression tables) look awful on it. How do I make specific tables in my document (not all of them) render as per the default bootstrap style?

I suspect this can be done by defining a custom css class and then modifying the function that creates the regression table to include that custom class, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant or simpler way.

If I use `bookdown::gitbook` to render my Rmd file, it looks like the one on the left, which just looks broken. If I use `bookdown::html_document2` or `bookdown::html_book`, it looks like the one on the right, which is what I want. I prefer how gitbook renders everything else though.

[image: Left: Gitbook | Right: Boostrap]

Comment: I agree the tables do not look pretty. I'd at least remove the vertical lines by `.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table td, .book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table th { border-left: none; border-right: none; }` in CSS.

Comment: Personally I think the extra spacing between sections of the regression table are more annoying. Removing the vertical lines helps a bit but the table still looks ugly.

Comment: Is there any new development in this regard @YihuiXie?

Comment: @Julian It's been too long, so I may not remember well, but you may try to set the option `table_css` to `false` in `bookdown::gitbook`. Then you can bring your own CSS rules for tables. See `?bookdown::gitbook`.

Comment: Yes I tried that one as well (and it works), however, I was wondering where I can find the table-css from gitbook, such that I can reuse that and just turn off the stripes.