# Remove all Table CSS from `bookdown::gitbook`

Tags: css, r, bookdown

I'm toying `bookdown` to write some documentation for `pixiedust` that I feel might be a bit too lengthy for a vignette.  I like the layout of `bookdown::gitbook`, but that, unfortunately, comes with its own table styling that is problematic for me.  Since `pixiedust` is all about styling tables, it is a little challenging to show what `pixiedust` has done (or hasn't done) with the default gitbook styling.

I've tried clearing the CSS with guidance from

[R bookdown gitbook - how to override table style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331971/r-bookdown-gitbook-how-to-override-table-style)

and

[How to change the code padding effect of gitbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339525/how-to-change-the-code-padding-effect-of-gitbook)

I've had no luck with putting the css code in a css file in my root directory and putting the file name in the `css` YAML tag.  I've had no luck with making a `styles` subdirectory.  And the version below hasn't worked either.

````
--- 
title: "Sample Book"
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    config:
      toc:
        collapse: section
        scroll_highlight: true
        before: null
        after: null
      theme: null
      css: ".book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table td, .book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table th { border-left: none; border-right: none; }"
---

```{r, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
library(pixiedust)

dust(head(mtcars))
```
````

Everything I've tried produces a table that looks like

[image]

What I'd like is something that looks like

[image]

At the moment, my root directory is empty save for the `index.Rmd` file with the code given above.

I'm using R 3.2.2 and `bookdown` 0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but you can remove some of the styling by replacing it with some "default" CSS in your markdown above the chunk displaying the table:

````
```{r results="asis", echo=FALSE}
cat("
<style>
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table
{
  width:auto;
}
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table td,
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table th,
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table tr
{
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  background-color:#fff;
}
</style>
")
```
````

You can look for CSS resets and add more if you need to.

Comment: It may not be ideal, but including this _at the start of each chapter_ of the book gives the appearance I want.  (emphasis left for future reference when I inevitably forget how to do this again)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a css reset class. Either with a bunch of properties you care about or try the [new `all` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#search=all) if internet explorer support is not important to you.

```
.reset{
    all: initial;
}
```

Or

```
.reset{
    border: initial;
    padding: initial;
    ...
}
```

Then apply to the table:

```
<table class="reset">
```

Comment: A clever idea.  At the moment, however, I have no way of assigning a new class to a table.  Though I may consider that option as I think about the benefits.